# Get ISO-dates out of an neo4j node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Within a graph there are Person-Nodes which have properties with information about the birthday and place of birth of a person e.g.

> Jaroslavice 8.10.1679
>
> Alcudia 26.7.1689

Is it possible to get ISO-dates and the place out of that property of type text and put it in new properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

One way would be to search for nodes that do not contain your new property; then use the `split` function to divide the text on spaces 
and periods; and then reassemble the date in the format you require.

Something like this...

```
MATCH (person:Person)
WHERE NOT exists(person.birthdate)
WITH person, 
split(person.informations,' ')[0] AS place,
split(person.informations,' ')[1] AS date
WITH person, 
place, 
split(date,'.')[0] AS day,
split(date,'.')[1] AS month,
split(date,'.')[2] AS year
SET person.birth_place = place,
person.birthdate = substring('0000', 0, 4 - size(year)) + year 
    + '-' 
    + substring('00', 0, 2 - size(month)) + month 
    + '-' 
    + substring('00', 0, 2 - size(day)) + day
```

Comment: According to the standard, the values of the year, month and day must be padding with leading zeros.

Comment: Roger that - I added a little leading zero padding to firm it up. Interesting to read about years prior to 1583.